# Set Expires header for an existing S3 object using AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-s3, http-headers, amazon-web-services

I'm updating existing objects in an Amazon S3 bucket to set some metadata.  I'd like to set the HTTP `Expires` header for each object to better handle HTTP/1.0 clients.

We're using the [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), which allows for metadata changes to an object without re-uploading the object content.  We do this using [CopyObjectRequest](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.html) to copy an object to itself.  The [ObjectMetadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html) class allows us to set the `Cache-Control`, `Content-Type` and several other headers.  But not the `Expires` header.

I know that S3 stores and serves the `Expires` header for objects PUT using the REST API. Is there a way to do this from the Java SDK?

**Updated to indicate that we are using** `CopyObjectRequest`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the [metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) of an existing [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) object, you need to copy the object to itself and provide the desired new metadata on the fly, see [copyObject()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#copyObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest%29):

> By default, all object metadata for the source object are copied to
>   the new destination object, unless new object metadata in the
>   specified CopyObjectRequest is provided.

This can be achieved like so approximately (fragment from the top of my head, so beware):

```
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client();

String bucketName = "bucketName ";
String key = "key.txt";
ObjectMetadata newObjectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
// ... whatever you desire, e.g.:
newObjectMetadata.setHeader("Expires", "Thu, 21 Mar 2042 08:16:32 GMT");

CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest()
                 .WithSourceBucketName(bucketName)
                 .WithSourceKey(key)
                 .WithDestinationBucket(bucketName)
                 .WithDestinationKey(key)
                 .withNewObjectMetadata(newObjectMetadata);

s3.copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

Please be aware of the following easy to miss, but important [copyObject()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#copyObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest%29) constraint:

> The Amazon S3 Acccess Control List (ACL) is **not** copied to the new
>   object. The new object will have the default Amazon S3 ACL,
>   CannedAccessControlList.Private, unless one is explicitly provided in
>   the specified CopyObjectRequest.

This is **not** accounted for in my code fragment yet!

Good luck!

Comment: I should have explained better that we are using `CopyObjectRequest` to do this now.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: The `ObjectMetadata.setHeader` is marked as internal use only.  Have you used this successfully?  Our code is only going to be run once, so we won't need to worry about it later if Amazon makes changes.  But YMMV.

Comment: Hmmh, I wasn't aware of that restriction indeed, but recall having used `Expires:` at some point a while back; I might be wrong though, insofar I often use other SDKs for interacting with S3 (e.g. C#/Python, which do definitely support this) and could have mixed that up - the code itself doesn't differ from the other `setXYZHeader()` methods currently (see [ObjectMetadata.java](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.java#L141)), so the restriction would be based on a non visible side effect, if any.

Comment: It's probably used by the other header methods internally and internal only because only certain headers will work.  They should add a `setExpires` method on `ObjectMetadata` as it's the only header that doesn't have it's own method.

Comment: @SteffenOpel What is the "right" date for Expires value? 2042 or 2014 or 2024? What is depends from this date? Is this a reason to set date to 2042 (or any far date)?

Comment: @flinth - there's no 'right' date (I just made that up back then), it entirely depends on your use case; you might want to read Yahoo's classic [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) though, which explains one specific use case for implementing a _"Never expire" policy by setting far future Expires header_ for static components, see section _Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header_ on the linked page for details - please also check [Controlling Freshness with the Expires HTTP Header](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#EXPIRES) in case.

Comment: @SteffenOpel thanks for your reply, I will check this sources, right now I asked a question about cache-control and expires, maybe this links helps me, thank you. May be you'll find interesting my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642446/amazon-s3-cache-control-and-expiry-date-difference-and-setting-trough-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

We were looking for a similar solution and eventually settled for max-age cache-control directive. And we eventually realized that hte cache-control overrides the Expires even if expires is more restrictive. And anyways cache-control met our requirement as well.

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely correct `Cache-Control` supersedes the `Expires` header.  Still, we'd like to include it for HTTP/1.0 clients that do not respect `Cache-Control`.