# Rails AWS-SDK: Set Expiration Date for Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

In my Rails app, I allow users to upload images directly to S3, which creates a temporary file that gets automatically deleted after the image record is saved in the database.

Instead of automatically deleting the image after the record is saved, I'd like to set an expiration date for the file on S3 so that it automatically gets deleted after a period (say 24 hours).

I've seen documentation on how to set the expiration date on a bucket (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/BucketLifecycleConfiguration.html), but I only want a certain folder within the bucket to have files that automatically get removed.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to do it?

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'])
foldername = @image.s3_filepath.split("/")[5]
folder_path = 'uploads/' + foldername
s3.buckets[ENV['AWS_BUCKET']].objects.with_prefix(folder_path).each( #set expiration date header here)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the lifecycle configuration on the bucket itself, not each individual object. Using the rest api you'd just write out an xml configuration (there's a field for `prefix` that let's you only apply this lifecycle config to those keys prefixed by it) and `PUT` it into the bucket.

Converting that over to the ruby SDK, it looks like the example *is* doing what you want; that first parameter of add_rule appears to be the prefix.

Comment: ok, too bad you can't set it for individual files. definitely scary to set an expiration date for the entire bucket if you have other sensitive files you don't want to expire...

Comment: Playing with the S3 web UI, it looks to me like you *can* apply the rule to an individual object (file) by specifying the full path to the file in the filter. It does seem odd that you have to set expiration rules for folders and objects at the top-level bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Although you set the lifecycle on the bucket, you don't set it on the bucket object directly.  You need to use the AWS::S3::BucketLifecycleConfiguration class.  There is more about how to manage life cycle here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/BucketLifecycleConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can now specify a folder or prefix within a bucket to narrow the lifecycle rule.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue that you have and it seems that the AWS documentation for rails apps it doesn't say to much about how to send this parameter through the `write` method. Here you have some links where they describe how to upload a file to S3 bucket [AWS SDK for Ruby](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) and [Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for Ruby](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html).

#### Using AWS SDK for Ruby - Version 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

bucket_name = '*** Provide bucket name ***'
file_name = '*** Provide file name ****'

# Get an instance of the S3 interface.
s3 = AWS::S3.new

# Upload a file.
key = File.basename(file_name)
s3.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => file_name)
puts "Uploading file #{file_name} to bucket #{bucket_name}."
```

This also was a good source for me [Amazon S3: Cache-Control and Expiry Date difference and setting trough REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642446/amazon-s3-cache-control-and-expiry-date-difference-and-setting-trough-rest-api) but still he doesn't mention how to setup the expiration date, or any of the answers or links that are there.

So I went through the documentation of the code itself (I'm using the aws-sdk-v1 gem) and I found here [Method: AWS::S3::S3Object#write](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aws-sdk-v1/1.66.0/AWS%2FS3%2FS3Object%3Awrite) all the possible options that allow us to configure the upload of the S3 object, however there was two that seemed to work for the same purpose:

- :metadata (Hash) - A hash of metadata to be included with the object. These will be sent to S3 as headers prefixed with x-amz-meta. Each name, value pair must conform to US-ASCII.
- :expires (String) - The date and time at which the object is no longer cacheable.

So I started looking which of them should I configure, and I found here [Set content expires and cache-control metadata for AWS S3 objects with Ruby](http://www.thehorrors.org.uk/snippets/aws-ruby-s3-set-content-expires-data/) what I was looking for:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => 'your_access_key',
  :secret_access_key => 'your_secret_access_key')

bucket = s3.buckets['bucket_name']

one_year_in_seconds = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
one_year_from_now = Time.now + one_year_in_seconds

# for a new object / to update an existing object
o = bucket.objects['object']
o.write(:file => 'path_to_file', 
    :cache_control => "max-age=#{one_year_in_seconds}", 
    :expires => one_year_from_now.httpdate)

# to update an existing object
o.copy_to(o.key, 
    :cache_control => "max-age=#{one_year_in_seconds}", 
    :expires => one_year_from_now.httpdate)
```

And that is pretty much what I've done in order to configure the expiration date and cache control, here is the code adapted to the app where I'm working on:

```
one_year_in_seconds = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
files.each do |path, s3path|
  #puts "Uploading #{path} to s3: #{File.join(prefix, s3path)}"
  s3path = File.join(prefix, s3path) unless prefix.nil?
  one_year_from_now = Time.now + one_year_in_seconds
  bucket.objects[File.join(s3path)].write(
    :file => path,
    :acl => (public == true ? :public_read : :private),
    :cache_control => "max-age=#{one_year_in_seconds}",
    :expires => one_year_from_now.httpdate
  )
end
```

Also here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html you will find the necessary support for the decision that I've done of configure `expires` and `cache_control` instead of metadata:

- The Cache-Control max-age directive lets you specify how long (in seconds) that you want an object to remain in the cache before CloudFront gets the object again from the origin server. The minimum expiration time CloudFront supports is 0 seconds for web distributions and 3600 seconds for RTMP distributions. The maximum value is 100 years. Specify the value in the following format:
  Cache-Control: max-age=seconds
  For example, the following directive tells CloudFront to keep the associated object in the cache for 3600 seconds (one hour):
  Cache-Control: max-age=3600
  If you want objects to stay in CloudFront edge caches for a different duration than they stay in browser caches, you can use the Cache-Control max-age and Cache-Control s-maxage directives together. For more information, see Specifying the Amount of Time that CloudFront Caches Objects for Web Distributions.
- The Expires header field lets you specify an expiration date and time using the format specified in RFC 2616, Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 Section 3.3.1, Full Date, for example:
  Sat, 27 Jun 2015 23:59:59 GMT

Regarding your question, yes you can specify an expiration date and a cache control date per each object in your bucket.

Comment: This is a useful answer to a different question. "Expires" and "Cache-Control" are headers sent in response to an HTTP request, instructing HTTP clients how to cache the full HTTP response. In other words, those settings tell your browser how long to keep a local copy of the object after downloading. They don't have anything to do with how long S3 stores the object, which is what this question is about.